# PHP and SQLite via PDO - wont to insert data

Tags: php, sqlite

I have simple code which inserts users to SQLite3 database via PDO and looks like

```
$db = new PDO('sqlite:myDB.db');

try {    

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
            id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
            name TEXT, 
            address TEXT,
            city TEXT)";

    $db->exec($sql);

    $data = array( 'name' => 'Baba Ganush', 'addr' => '123 Test Dr', 'city' => 'Test City' );

    $insert = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (name, address, city) value (:name, :addr, :city)");
    $insert->execute((array)$data);

}
catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
}

$db = null;
```

but it throws an error that `mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in` a line `$insert->execute((array)$data);` when `$data` is an array.

What I have missed?

Comment: `$addUser` is an object which you cannot redeclare and cannot cast to an array.

Comment: @JayBlanchard so should I move out of objects in that case or there is a way to get it done with an object?

Comment: If you do not need an object, just set an array.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I have moved to use an array but still getting the same error message. OP updated.